Continuity without topology nor $\epsilon$-$\delta$
I was reading this question, and the related answers, which popped out in merit to my previous question about continuity while searching over here: $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ where $0$ is isolated in the domain of $f$?
Now as fare as I understood there are two main ways to prove that function is continuous at $x = 0$: the topological one and the analytical one ($\epsilon$-$\delta$), and in the latter case it turns out to be that the definition is vacuously satisfied.
I was wondering: is there some other way to prove that $f: \{0\} \cup (2, 3)$ with $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous at $x = 0$?
I apologise for the questions, hoping it's not meaningless. I am just curious: I thought to put myself into some non mathematics student, someone rather far from the mathematical world, hence like some amateur or biology students (and don't get this wrong, I'm not denigrating biologists, I am just saying that they don't have to know and study those rigorous definition for continuity), with the will to understand continuity in some easy way. Is there something or are those the only two ways?
Thank you!!
EDIT: what do I mean?
The "idea" (which I believe will turn out into something trivial or wrong) came from the approach to continuity in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where for what I understood reading over here certain answers and questions is something like: "$f(x, y)$ is continuous at a point $(x_0, y_0)$ in the domain, if I can find a function of a distance (whether it be the Euclidean distance or another one), such that
$$|f(x, y) - f(x_0, y_0)| \leq h(d(x, y))$$
Where $h(d(x, y))$ is a distance function, for example I could have $h = x^2+y^2$ or $h = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ or $h = |x|+|y|$ and so on.
This is good because we know that distances have the property to go to zero when the argument is zero, that is for example when $(x_0, y_0) \to (0, 0)$ we have $h(d(0, 0)) \to 0$ as it happens with the above distances.
Example:
$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\\\ 0 & (x, y) = (0, 0) \end{cases}$$
Continuity at zero:
$$\vert|f(x, y) - f(0, 0)\vert| = \bigg|\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\bigg| = x \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} \leq x \to 0$$
Hence $f$ is continuous at zero.
So?
What I mean hence is: can we do the same in $\mathbb{R}$? For example: say we have $f(x) = x^2$ with domain the whole real axis. Then the continuity, say, at $x = 4$ would read something like
$$|f(x) - f(4)| = |x^2-4| \leq x^2$$
And $x^2$ is a distance in $\mathbb{R}$ so we are done.

Is this nonsense? Is this the actual $\epsilon-\delta$ "revised"?

I mean in this case it would be trivial to show $x^2$ is continuous at $x = 0$, when the domain is $\{0\} \cup (2, 3)$.

Can you give an indication of how something like this might go?  When I read the question all I can see is "how can I show something is continuous without using what continuity means?"

@Randall I will edit the question, you're right!

I suppose the most basic non-rigourous definition of continuity is that when you're drawing the graph, the function on each connected bit of the domain can be drawn without taking the pencil off the paper until it's completed. A single point can be completed without the need to take the pencil off the paper partway through.

You certainly need some conditions on $h$. Then this amounts to something equivalent to the definitions you’re disallowing.

@TedShifrin Yes, indeed $h$ is a function of a distance, which is maybe a too fancy way to just say "a distance function", such that it satisfies the three properties of a distance

Not any old function. You certainly need $h(0)=0$ and continuity of $h$ at $0$ … $h$ itself has nothing to do with distance.

Just a remark: the general definition of continuity is the topological one. A topology is enough to fully define continuity. Once you have a distance, you can trivially define a topology through open balls by saying that an open set is an union of open balls: that is called a metric space. And the absolute difference of 2 real numbers defines a distance on $\Bbb R$, which leads the $\varepsilon, \delta$ definition or continuity.

Well, let's make a global recall of the two ways you mentioned, that is the analytical and the topological. I'll give some "extras" in the end, but consider the comment of @Ted Shifrin as a concise answer.

Let $f: A\to \mathbb{R}$ where $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, and consider $x_0 \in A$. Then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $|x-x_0|< \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$, where of course $x \in A$.

This definition can be rewritten in terms of neighbourhoods:

A function $f: A\to \mathbb{R}$ where again $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x_0 \in A$ if for every neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$ there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $x \in A \cap U$ implies $f(x) \in V$.

The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition corresponds to the case when $V$ is an $\epsilon-$neighbourhood of $f(x_0)$ and $U$ is a $\delta-$neighbourhood of $x_0$.
Note: $x_0$ must belong to the domain of $f$ in order to define the continuity of $f$ at $x_0$.
Note: If $x_0$ is an isolated point of the domain, the continuity condition holds automatically since for any sufficient small $\delta > 0$ the only point $x \in A$ with $|x - x_0| < \delta$ is $x = x_0$ itself, and hence
$$0 = |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$$
This is why a function is always continuous at every isolated point of its domain. Isolated points are not much of interest, though they can be used to create interesting exercises.
Note: When $x_0$ is not an isolated point it's a limit point (or accumulation point) for the domain, hence you surely know the equivalent condition of continuity of $f(x)$ at $x_0$:
$$f(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$$
Examples
Because they always make people to understand "more".
$\color{red}{One}$
Be $A = \left\{0; 1; \frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{3}; \ldots; \frac{1}{n} \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\} \right\}$ and be $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(0) = K$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = K_n$, where $K, K_n \in \mathbb{R}$.
The point $\frac{1}{n}$ is an isolated point for each $n$ natural as defined above, so $f$ is continuous at every $\frac{1}{n}$ independently of the choice of $K_n$.
Notice that $A$ is closed because it does contain $0$ which is the only limit point of $A$, and hence here we have $\lim_{n\to +\infty} K_n = K$ which is the must have condition for continuity of $f$ at $0$.
This example can be useful for what you might not (?) have studied when dealing with continuity, which is often called "the Heine criterion" for continuity, even if the most of people DO NOT really name in in that way, nor in others (my professor did, so I kept doing it).

Theorem. If $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in A$ is a limit point, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if for every sequence $a_n \in A$ such that

$a_n \neq x_0$
$a_n \to x_0$ for $n\to +\infty$



we have $\lim_{n\to +\infty} f(a_n) = f(x_0)$.
In particular $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$ if there does exist a sequence $a_n$ as above, but such that $f(a_n) \not\to f(x_0)$ as $n\to+\infty$.

Note: You cannot use this theorem for isolated points. Trivial to say, but let's say it anyway.
Now let's talk a bit about "your way" to do continuity.
$\color{red}{Two.}$
Be $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$, recall that $0 \in\mathbb{R}^+$. Be $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and let's prove $f$ is continuous at $x_0 \in\mathbb{R}^+$. We can indeed show and write that
$$|f(x) - f(x_0)| = |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}| = \bigg| \dfrac{x-x_0}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}}\bigg| \leq \frac{x-x_0}{\sqrt{x_0}}$$
This is rather near to what you thought of, from $\mathbb{R}^2$ in your example. Though now we have to go on, maybe choosing $x_0 = 0$ as a pedagogical example. Notice that $x_0 = 0$ looks like annoying for what we did here above.
Given $\epsilon > 0$ we can then choose $\delta = \epsilon \sqrt{x_0} > 0$ in the definition.
Using $x_0 = 0$, we note $0 \leq x < \delta$, where $\delta = \epsilon^2 > 0$, hence
$$|f(x) - f(0)| = \sqrt{x} < \epsilon$$
which is just the initial statement of continuity without the fancy rewriting. Since $\sqrt{x} \to 0$ as $x\to 0$, we can say $\sqrt{x} < \epsilon$ behaves "like a distance" (though I suggest you to not think of distances at all...) in $\mathbb{R}$, but we really need more focus and precision.
$\color{red}{Three.}$
Another interesting example based on upper bounding.
$f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = \sin(x)$. We prove the continuity at a general point $x_0$ of the domain, and we will make use of the fact that $|\sin(x)| < |x|$ for every $x$.
$$|\sin(x) - \sin(x_0)| = \bigg|2\cos\left(\dfrac{x+x_0}{2}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{x-x_0}{2}\right)\bigg| \leq 2\bigg|\sin\left(\dfrac{x-x_0}{2}\right)\bigg| \leq |x - x_0|$$
This is almost done, we just need to choose $\epsilon = \delta$ in the definition of continuity, for every $x_0$ in the domain.
I hope this helps you even a little bit.
Exercise: try to formalize the continuity of $f(x) = x^2$ at $x = 2.5$, in your example.
Then try to see if $f(x) = x^2$, defined in the whole $\mathbb{R}$ is also uniformly continuous or not, it's always a nice exercise.

Well thank you really a lot for all of this. I did not know the "sequences Theorem", and for what concerns uniform continuity, I'll try!

A genuine alternative to both epsilon-delta and topological definitions is provided by calculus with infinitesimals.  To take your example: a function $f$ will be continuous at $x=4$ if and only if the following condition is satisfied: an infinitesimal change $\alpha$ in the value of $x$ always produces an infinitesimal change in the value of the function.  This definition of continuity appears in Cauchy's famous 1821 textbook Cours d'Analyse.  In other words, $f(4+\alpha)$ will always be infinitely close to $f(4)$.  Such a relation of infinite proximity is sometimes denoted $\approx$, so that the condition can be stated as follows: if $\alpha\approx0$ then $f(4+\alpha)\approx f(4)$.
For further details, and a similar simplified approach to compactness, see

Hrbacek, K.; Katz, M. "Effective infinitesimals in ℝ." Real Analysis Exchange 48 (2023), no. 2, 365-380. https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.09672, https://doi.org/10.14321/realanalexch.48.2.1671048854, https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=4668954

